# Create database link between three instances oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, database-link

How to create database link between three instances?
For eg i have database named orcl,orcl1,orcl2 how to link them?
Thanks

Comment: It's too broad question. Can you describe what you are actually want to achieve as how to create database link really easy to find out from Oracle docs

Comment: It's not much complexity to find out on google, but still, I have posted an answer below you can check out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the below SQL that might be helpful to you :)

**At database ORCL:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orcl1
CONNECT TO orcl1_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl1_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl1';

CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orcl2
CONNECT TO orcl2_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl2_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl2';
```

**At database ORCL1:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orcl
CONNECT TO orcl_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl';

CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orc2
CONNECT TO orcl2_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl2_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl2';
```

**At database ORCL2:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orcl
CONNECT TO orcl_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl';

CREATE DATABASE LINK db_link_orcl1
CONNECT TO orcl1_user_name IDENTIFIED BY orcl1_user_password 
USING 'localhost:1521/orcl1';
```

Comment: can i get to know how to create a view for these tables as i am a student and have no idea about sql

Comment: Create or replace view view_name as select * from table_name@db_link_name;         That’s all